# Why did Esmeralda jump into the garbage container?

Tags: plot-explanation, pulp-fiction

In *Pulp Fiction* Esmeralda sips her coffee, listening to the commentary on a boxing match between Butch Coolige and Willis on her radio. She shuts off the radio and throws it from the balcony, where she also jumps from and lands in the garbage container. Why did she jump into the garbage container?

Comment: "throws it from the balcony, where she also jumps from and lands in the garbage container. Why did she jump into garbage container?" This does not happen. That's Butch escaping. She's in the cab.

Comment: You may want to watch that scene again.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As pointed out in the comments, Esmeralda is listening to her radio in her taxicab. She sees Butch jump out of the window of his dressing room after Butch throws some of his belongings out of the same window during his post-bout escape. Her intuition kicks in as she recognizes the hasty exit as a sure-fire fare who won’t have the time to hail a cab. Nor will he want to draw attention to himself. So, she starts the meter (not normally done until picking up the paying customer), throws the car in gear, and slams on the gas with her bare foot. She pulls up to the scene to provide Butch with ready transportation before he even knows it. It’s like she read his mind, or he willed the taxi into being. Either way. Butch was not going to quibble with serendipity. He needed the ride, post haste. And, now. After all, he was standing in an alley in Nothing but boxing shorts, mat shoes, and an overcoat or robe. His clothes (the aforementioned belongings) in hand.

Comment: I've always thought that Butch pre-arranged taxi to be waiting by the rubbish container. He would be stupid not to as he would be chased pretty soon.

Comment: @Greendrake - This depends on the city. City laws will determine whether you can prearrange a taxi versus prearranging a car service. Either way, he would have to tell a dispatcher to have a taxi waiting at a specific time - at a dumpster - in a dark alley. That is pretty sketchy. What driver would take that fare. Plus, when would Butch know that the fight would be over? And, he would have no time between waking up that morning and jumping out of the window to use the phone.